# Why are there two? activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk6c5.png)

During the compatibility test, I inadvertently pressed alt+enter and it became two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio has 2 layout activity files for the same activity. Is it necessary? How do I keep 1 file for all newer SDK verions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041018/android-studio-has-2-layout-activity-files-for-the-same-activity-is-it-necessar)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that this layout file will be used for Android devices with api 26 and above. If you will go to the actual files in your computer, you will see a folder named layout-v26. you will find there the file and you can delete it.